# Images not shown properly in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to use some images with ASP.NET MVC. I've created a folder to store them and then I've pulled them from the solution explorer to code.

View code :

`<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">
  <img src="~/Images/Logo.png" width="125" height="74" class="img-responsive" />
  <img src="~/Images/Logo.png" />
</a>`

Code of the page when inspected on Google Chrome :

`<img src="/Images/Logo.png" width="125" height="74" class="img-responsive">`

When I run the application they appeared broken on the browser. I have checked the path, properties, and everything is correct, but I can't fix this.

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? If you navigate to `yoursite.com/Images/Logo.png` do you see the image? What does your browser's network tools say when loading the page? What status code does it give for the images?

Comment: Try losing the tilde (~) in front of the path.  I've found it's not necessary and sometimes has left me with similar problems on loading images.  Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

you could trying using @Raw

```
<dd>
    <img src="~/Images/@Html.Raw(Model.PhotoUrl)" alt="Image" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"/>
</dd>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the problem. I create a folder name "Images" in solution explorer to store all my images, but that was conflit with the forder "images" in the "CSS" folder. I move my image to the "image" folder in "CSS" folder and everything works perfect.